# Color different values in a Pandas dataframe a different color on a scatterpot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `df` such as this:

```
Date                   Sig
2020-06-16 09:00:00    1
2020-06-16 13:00:00    0
2020-06-16 17:00:00   -1
2020-06-16 21:00:00   -1
2020-06-17 01:00:00    0
2020-06-17 05:00:00    1
2020-06-17 09:00:00    1
2020-06-17 13:00:00    0
2020-06-17 17:00:00    0
2020-06-17 21:00:00    -1
```

What I'm trying to do is a simple scatter plot in Matplotlib with the index as the X axis and the `Sig` column on the Y, but only showing 1s and -1s, with 1 colored blue and -1 colored red. But I don't want a 0 row to be omitted from the scatter plot if that makes sense.

I can obviously just do the scatter plot thusly 'plt.scatter(x=df.index, y=df['Sig'])' but that of course plots all numbers in `Sig` and doesn't color code them.

Any help would be really appreciated. Cheers

Comment: In the arguments you could use something like`facecolor = ["blue" if s>0 else "red" for s in df["Sig"]]`. We can add an extra if/else for a third color when the data is exactly 0 if you need.

Comment: Namely `facecolor = [{-1: "red", 0: "black", 1: "blue"}[sign] for sign in df["Sig"]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a groupby on filtered data like this:

```
# datetime data type is recommended
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

colors = ['r','b']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for c, (k,d) in zip(colors, df[df['Sig']!=0].groupby('Sig')):
    d.plot.scatter(x='Date',y='Sig',label=k, ax=ax, c=c)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`plt.scatter` supports iterables of colors, so you can actually give each point an independent color.

Here, we will simply have a dictionary with three choices dictated by the sign of your data:

```
colors = {-1: "red", 0: "black", +1: "blue"}
plt.scatter(x=df.index, y=df["Sig"], color=[colors[sign] for sign in df["Sig"]])
```